# Get class from elementFromPoint?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need a bit of help using elementFromPoint, how would retrieve the class of the div?

```
<div id="years" class="era">
```

id gives me years, tagName gives div. Does anyone if getting the class is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the element, the look at its className property.

```
var className = document.getElementById("years").className;
```

Comment: doh didn't think of it that way, was too busy thinking of how to reference the class with elementFromPoint. Thanks